Grouping dynamically created ToggleButtons (to turn off/on in groups) and writing into class
I have a list of possible locations (i) and want the user to bring into order of preference.
Therefore, I have written code to create the "i" locations and assigned ToggleButtons (= TB). I'm getting a field of i x i TB where "a" preference is already selected (i.e. if clicking "Next" each location has one preference)

'create Toggle buttons
        Dim mpp         As Long
        Dim i           As Long
        Dim j           As Long
        Dim A_ij        As Long
        Dim TB          As MSForms.ToggleButton
        Dim txtBox      As MSForms.Label
'        Dim btnColl     As New Collection
        
        'A_ij = 0
        mpp = 1
        'read out how many "add" items
        For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value

            'Toggle Buttons
            For j = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value
                Set TB = MultiPage1.Pages(mpp - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.ToggleButton.1", "TB_" & i & "_" & j)
                TB.Name = i & j
                TB.Caption = j
                TB.Left = 5 + 20 * (j - 1)
                TB.width = 20
                TB.Height = 20
                TB.Top = 15 + ((i - 1) * 20)
                If TB.Caption = i Then
                    TB.Value = True
                    Else
                    TB.Value = False
                End If
                A_ij = TB.Name
                ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To A_ij)
                Set cmdArray(A_ij).CmdEvents = TB

                Set TB = Nothing
            Next j
            
            'Label boxes
            Set txtBox = MultiPage1.Pages(mpp - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label_" & i)
            txtBox.Caption = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 31, 4).Value
            txtBox.Left = 10 + 20 * (Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value)
            txtBox.width = 390
            txtBox.Top = 17 + ((i - 1) * 20)
            
            

        Next i

I now want to achieve/write code that if user presses "1" in location "Restaurant A", the TB_6_1.Value is set to True (automatically) with all others in that row getting set to False.
Therefore I thought to add them to an array or collection (if I read this correctly) for each i (which I found code to and seems to work -> it runs, but I don't quite understand how to read out in class)
I found to create a class with
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.ToggleButton

Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()

    MsgBox Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mpp         As Long
    mpp = 1
    Dim ctl As Control
    
    For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value
        'set TB_Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1)_i which isn't the one clicked to False; if i = name True (which is done by pressing it)

'        MsgBox cmdArray(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1) & i).CmdEvents
        
'    For Each ctl In Me.Controls 'but want just those with name starting same i
'        If ctl.Name <> CmdEvents.Name Then
'            ctl.Value = False
'        End If
    Next i

End Sub 

In theory: I want to check first digit of my clicked TB and then set all other TB with the same first digit to false.  I would prefer being able to work in Class1 for all rows since I don't know how many possible locations I have. (i.e. thought about writing Class i for every i)
This article gave me the class code idea: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/toggle-buttons.318583/
This article gave me the structure for the UserForm code: Assign Sub to dynamically defined CommandButton
This article helped: Assign code to a button created dynamically however, I want these changes to occur to the TB before I click "Next" (CommandButton) to save user's preference. So I'm not sure where to put them in regards to sub/function/class/module.
Update:
I've found a way in class to set all TB in the row to false; however, I realised that setting them to false is a Click event and thus the loop runs again, so I'm not sure how to keep the pressed button true...
For Each ctl In Order.Controls 
            If Left(ctl.Name, 2) = Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) Then 'And ctl.Name <> CmdEvents.Name
                ctl.Value = False
'                If ctl.Name = CmdEvents.Name Then
'                    ctl.Value = True
'                End If
            End If
        Next ctl

Since I know specific names which I want to call, I'm wondering if I can call those rather than looping through ALL controls. However, I'm trying to set a TB false which in turns calls another click_event.
For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value
'        MsgBox Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Value
'        MsgBox i
'        MsgBox Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1)
        If Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Value And i <> Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1) Then
            nv = Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Name
            GoTo setF
'            Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Value = False
        End If
    Next i
setF:
    If nv = Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Name Then '<-- this line gives me a debug error when it changes one false and thus enters loop again
        Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Value = False
    End If


I've worked some more in the class and was able to solve (maybe not elegantly):

Here is the class code:
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.ToggleButton

Dim mpp         As Long
Dim i           As Long

Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()

    
    Dim dn           As Long
    mpp = Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1)
    dn = 0
    'if Clicking off
    If CmdEvents.Value = False Then
        'set backcolor to off
        CmdEvents.BackColor = vbButtonFace
        'check all items in list to set to green
        For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value ' column number
            'check if TB is true
            If Order.Controls(mpp & i & Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1)) Then
                dn = dn + 1
            End If
        Next i
        If dn = 1 Then
            For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value ' column number
                'check if TB is true
                If Order.Controls(mpp & i & Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1)) Then
                    Order.Controls(mpp & i & Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1)).BackColor = RGB(0, 128, 64) 'green
                    GoTo np
                End If
            Next i
        End If
np:
        
        'remove item from preview
'        MsgBox Order.Controls("Listbox" & mpp).ListCount
'        MsgBox CmdEvents.Caption - 1
        If Order.Controls("Listbox" & mpp).ListCount >= CmdEvents.Caption - 1 Then
            Order.Controls("Listbox" & mpp).RemoveItem CmdEvents.Caption - 1
          Else
            Order.Controls("Listbox" & mpp).RemoveItem Sheets(1).Cells(Mid(CmdEvents.Name, 2, 1) + 30 + mpp + Sheets(1).Cells(10 + mpp, 5).Value, 4).Value - 1
        End If
        ' do nothing more
        GoTo EndNothing
        Else
        CmdEvents.BackColor = RGB(0, 128, 64) 'green
    End If
    'MsgBox "mpp: " & Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1) & vbCrLf & "i: " & Mid(CmdEvents.Name, 2, 1) ' reads out mpp and i
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim nv As Long
    nv = 0
    Dim trb As Long
'    Dim j As Long
        
    For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value
        If Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Value And i <> Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1) Then
            nv = Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Name
            Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 2) & i).Value = False
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Put name into Listbox
    If Order.Controls("Listbox" & mpp).ListCount > CmdEvents.Caption - 1 Then 'check length of listbox
        Order.Controls("Listbox" & mpp).AddItem Sheets(1).Cells(Mid(CmdEvents.Name, 2, 1) + 30 + mpp + Sheets(1).Cells(10 + mpp, 5).Value, 4).Value, CmdEvents.Caption - 1
      Else
        Order.Controls("Listbox" & mpp).AddItem Sheets(1).Cells(Mid(CmdEvents.Name, 2, 1) + 30 + mpp + Sheets(1).Cells(10 + mpp, 5).Value, 4).Value
    End If
    
    'Colour Red if same preference
    For Each ctl In Order.Controls
        If Left(ctl.Name, 1) = mpp Then 'if control is a TB button
            If Left(ctl.Name, 1) = Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1) And Right(ctl.Name, 1) = Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1) And ctl.Value = True And CmdEvents.Value = True And ctl.Name <> CmdEvents.Name Then
                ctl.BackColor = RGB(120, 105, 2) 'red
                CmdEvents.BackColor = RGB(120, 105, 2) 'red
                Else
                'reset green colour
                If Left(ctl.Name, 1) = Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1) And Right(ctl.Name, 1) = Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1) And ctl.Value = True And ctl.Name <> CmdEvents.Name Then
                   'only if not two buttons are pressed in column
                   'need to change "old" column colour as well
'                   For j = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value
                    trb = 0
                    For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(11 + mpp, 5).Value
                         If Order.Controls(Left(CmdEvents.Name, 1) & i & Right(CmdEvents.Name, 1)).Value Then 'j
                             trb = trb + 1
                         End If
                     Next i
                     MsgBox trb
                    If trb = 1 Then
                         ctl.BackColor = RGB(0, 128, 64) 'green
                    End If
'                  Next j
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
    
EndNothing:
End Sub

I also added some colour code and next page in multipage to Order Initialize:
For mpp = 1 To 2 'added version for alternative date
 ' the same
TB.Name = mpp & i & j 'altered for second "date" to work
 ' the same
If TB.Caption = i Then
                        TB.Value = True
                        TB.BackColor = RGB(0, 128, 64) 'added to give green background'
 ' the same
Next mpp
End Sub

